# How can I find a numerical solution to the following problem:

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

I have this evolution equation:

$\frac{d C(\mu)}{d\ln\mu}=[y(\mu)]^2C(\mu)$

and I have to find a numerical solution for $C$. The complication arises because I do not know the exact for of the function $y(\mu)$ but I only know its evolution equation with $\mu$ which looks something like:

$\frac{d y(\mu)}{d\ln\mu}=[y(\mu)]^3+y(\mu)[f_1(\mu)+f_2(\mu)]$

and it is complicated to analytically integrate to have a solution for $y(\mu)$. But I can numerically solve it because I know the evolution equations for $f_1$ and $f_2$ and I am able to derive a closed form for these functions.
I was wondering if there is a way I can tell Mathematica to numerically solve the first equation for C, while using the numerical result from the numerical solution for the function $y$? The whole problem is that I dont know how to get an analytic form for $y(\mu)$ or at least haven't been able till now.

Thanks a lot for any help or insight!

Comment: Why not just using  `NDSolve` to solve the _system_ consisting of $C$ and $y$? The documentation should show you how to do that.

Comment: What are your boundary conditions?